# Listen to child MenuItem Click

Tags: wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls

Is there a way for a parent MenuItem to be notified when a child MenuItem is pressed.
For example, I you have

```
<MenuItem Name='a'>
    <MenuItem Name='b' Header='...'/>
</MenuItem>
```

how can I add an event handler to a to be notified when b is clicked.
Ideally, the Click event would be either a tunnel or bubble event but this is not the case.
The solution I have in mind is to listen to the Click event on b and forward it to a but this seems pretty heavy handed.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MenuItem.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.click.aspx) is a routed event (it bubbles up), so you can just subscribe to it on the first `MenuItem` and be notified of all children at the same time.

XAML:

```
<MenuItem Name='a' Click='OnMenuItemClicked'>
    <MenuItem Name='b' Header='...' />
</MenuItem>
```

C#:

```
private void OnMenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
    if(null != item)
    {
        // Handle the menu item click here
    }
}
```

The trick is to use `RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource`, rather than `sender`. This points to the control that originally fired the event.